# Transformation matrix of a polynomial

Tags: matrices, polynomials, transformation

I would really appretiate some help about the following transformation matrices. 
We have to write a tranformation matrix in basis $B = \{ 1 + x, x + x^2, x^2 \}$ with a polynomial $(Ap)(x) = (x^2 - 2)p(1) - x ~ p'(x)$.

I do know how to write it in basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$, but I don't seem to get a correct answer for the basis $B$.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Are you trying to find the transformation matrix of $A$ using the basis $B$ for both the domain and the range? Are the polynomials degree 2 or less?

Comment: We have to find a transformation matrix of a transformation in R^3 space in respect to basis B. @matrini gave the right answer below, but i don't quite understand it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote the three elements of $B$ by $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$. We have
\begin{align*}
   Ap_1(x) &= (x^2 - 2)p_1(1) - xp_1'(x)\\
       &= 2x^2 - 4 - x\\
       &= -4(1+x) + 3x + 2x^2\\
       &= -4(1+x) + 3(x+x^2) - x^2\\
       &= -4p_1(x) + 3p_2(x) - 1p_3(x)
\end{align*}
I'm sure, you can do the other two along the same lines.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\text{can} = \{1, x, x^2\}$ be the standard basis for $\mathcal{P}_2(\Bbb R)$. You claim that you got the matrix $[A]_{\text{can}}$. We want $[A]_{\text{B}}$, if I understood you right. If $[I]_{B, \text{can}}$ is the matrix obtained putting the coordinates of $B$'s polynomials, in the $\text{can}$ basis, in columns, then we have: $$[A]_B = [I]_{B, \text{can}}^{-1} \cdot [A]_{\text{can}}\cdot [I]_{B, \text{can}}$$